# Why doesn't .gitignore.txt file show it's name in windows10?

Tags: windows, git, file, text, windows-10

Recently I scaffolded a project with webapp generator. It created two files `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes`. Both show a file extention of type `Text Document` But when I press F12 to edit any one's name then it has empty name. Here is the snapshot:

[image]

My question is why don't window show the name as `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 16):

There is nothing special with those files. This visual guide may help you.

[image: Windows Folder Options Image]

Also in Windows 10 you may simply try this option in View Tab of Folder Explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After looking and reading closer, it seems that the "problem" is that with the default settings of Explorer "known" file-name extensions (like e.g. `.txt`) are just not shown.

So if you name a file `.txt` (full file-name) then it will show up as empty and with no name.

---

Dot-files are not having any "extension" to their file-name. The full file-name of e.g. the Git ignore file *is* `.gitignore`.

It comes from the Unix world where file-names doesn't have to follow the DOS and Windows `name.ext` scheme, and means that the file is hidden.

Windows since long allows arbitrary file-names as well, but in a `name.ext` scheme such files doesn't have a "name" only an extension.

Comment: I saved a file with name `.txt` with format `txt` file. It has an empty name. Same goes for html files. But For any other extension, e.g. `.tcl` windows shows `.tcl` as its name. Why is this? Is empty name allowed for only specific file formats?

Comment: @6questions24hour Ah, I think I know what the problem is, and it's about that you have default setting for Explorer, which is to hide known extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Windows interprets `.gitignore` as an empty file name with the extension "gitignore", and thus shows an empty name be default. To properly see its name, open the folder's properties and check the "Show All File Extensions" option.

Comment: You mean uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types"?

Comment: @Eugene I believe that what's it called in modern Windows versions, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but I have a preference. I'd prefer not to show all extensions just to be able to see my `.gitignore` files in Windows10 file explorer.

I'm hoping to extend OP's question by showing I DO SEE `.babelrc` and `.eslintrc`, and w/o seeing all file extension setting being set to "on".

It seems, on my own system, that the associations for BABELRC and ESLINT(RC|IGNORE) are, maybe, set automatically by VSCode? In any case, why can I see those "." files, while the `in.json` is showing with hidden extension, but I can't see `.gitignore`?

[image: windows file explorer screen shot where .gitignore shows as blank]

[image: evidence screen shot showing the .gitignore is indeed present]